# C# Reflection - Get Generic Argument type of Super class from within the Base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection

Consider the classes:

```
public class Super : Base<Test, Super>
{
    public Super Next { get; set; }
}

public class Base<TArg, TSuper>
{
    public Type GetTestArgument()
    {
        Type[] arguments = typeof(TSuper).GetProperty("Next").PropertyType.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetGenericArguments();
        // arguments is set to [ TArg, TSuper ] instead of [ Test, Super ]
        return arguments[0]; // should be Test
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to get the generic type from within the base class without calling `typeof(TArg)` because I'll be iterating through other super classes properties and it must be via deeper reflection.

Thanks.

Comment: `typeof(TArg)`?

Comment: @Amy I edited to add information I had forgotten. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a call to `GetGenericTypeDefinition()`, which you probably don't want. I.e.:

```
typeof(TSuper).GetProperty("Next").PropertyType.BaseType.GetGenericArguments()
```

`typeof(TSuper).GetProperty("Next").PropertyType.BaseType` returns the type `Base<Test, Super>`. So calling `GetGenericArguments()` on it returns `[Test, Super]`.

Calling `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` on that gives you `Base<TArg, TSuper>`, and calling `GetGenericArguments()` on it returns `[TArg, TSuper]`.

Comment: Thanks! Silly mistake!